# aChartEngine, grid and thickness

Tags: java, android, grid, achartengine

I'm trying to conform a graphic similar than this one with aChartengine, but I can't find the method to get different thickness into the vertical grids like in the image, does anyone can help me?

[image]

Here it is my code: Is it posible to delete the lines connecting points??

```
 public Intent execute(Context context) {
        String[] titles = new String[] { "Systolic Pressure", "Diastolic Pressure", "BIS", "ETCO2"};
    List<double[]> x = new ArrayList<double[]>();
    for (int i = 0; i < titles.length; i++) {
    x.add(new double[] { 5, 10, 15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60 });
    }
       List<double[]> values = new ArrayList<double[]>();
         values.add(new double[] { 108, 110.5, 110, 115, 114, 118, 116, 119, 120, 125.3, 122.2,
             13.9 });
         values.add(new double[] { 75, 77, 80, 79, 82, 84, 83, 80, 86, 88, 85, 80 });
         values.add(new double[] { 5, 5.3, 8, 12, 17, 22, 24.2, 24, 19, 15, 9, 6 });
         values.add(new double[] { 9, 10, 11, 15, 19, 23, 26, 25, 22, 18, 13, 10 });
         int[] colors = new int[] { Color.BLUE, Color.RED, Color.CYAN, Color.YELLOW };
        PointStyle[] styles = new PointStyle[] { PointStyle.TRIANGLE, PointStyle.TRIANGLE,
             PointStyle.POINT, PointStyle.SQUARE};
         XYMultipleSeriesRenderer renderer = buildRenderer(colors, styles);

         setChartSettings(renderer, "Anesthesia sheet", "Time", " ", 0, 60, 0, 250,
             Color.WHITE, Color.WHITE);
         renderer.setXLabels(12);
         renderer.setYLabels(10);
         renderer.setShowGrid(true);
         renderer.setXLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
         renderer.setYLabelsAlign(Align.RIGHT);
         renderer.setZoomButtonsVisible(true);

         renderer.setPanLimits(new double[] { 0,60, 0, 250 });
         renderer.setZoomLimits(new double[] { 0, 60, 0, 250});

         XYMultipleSeriesDataset dataset = buildDataset(titles, x, values);
         Intent intent = ChartFactory.getLineChartIntent(context, dataset, renderer,
             "Anesthesia");
         return intent;   }
```

Here it is the graph in Android:
[image]

Comment: You can use renderer.setShowGridY(true); for vertical grid.

Comment: Thanks for your help @keshav, but what I'm trying is to get different thickness into the vertical grids like in the image, could you help me?

Comment: Thanks for your help @keshav, but what I'm trying is to get different thickness into the vertical grids like in the image, could you help me?

Comment: then u have to edit source of lib  according to ur requirement. You should have a look http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7675208/how-do-i-set-grid-depth-z-index-of-achartengine-in-android .

Comment: Yes @keshav it is what I've thought, but where can I modify those libraries?

Answer (score 0):

I know this question is way too old, but I guess it is very basic requirement to have a grid line width/thickness configurable, specially with Line charts using `achartengine`.

As discussed in the comments of this question, there is no API that `achartengine` Library itself provides to modify grid line width/thickness, hence below solution only work if you are willing to change source code of Library itself (with appropriate Legal Permissions of Library License).

File to Modify: `XYChart.java`
Method in which to modify: `drawXTextLabels`
Code you need to add to increase grid line width/thickness:

```
paint.setStrokeWidth(2);//adjust 2 to suitable value as per your requirement.
```

This above line of code need to be added before 
`canvas.drawLine(xLabel, bottom, xLabel, top, paint);` in `drawXTextLabels` method.

`achartengine` Library version: **1.0.0**

**NOTE: Above code will make ALL Grid lines thicker, and you need to set the thickness/width of Specific Grid Lines as per your Business Logic.**